# signalling inside php

Tags: php, multithreading, http

hi when implementing a connection that stays open for a long time ( comet ),
how would i implement signalling between php proses(outstanding requests)??

example timeline:

- request 1 start
- request 1 makes action
- request 1 sleeps
- request 2 start
- request 2 makes action
- request 2 notifies request 1 and go's to sleep
- request 1 wakes up and sends the new data
- request 1 sleeps agen

i was wandering if ther was a methode whitch use less(noting?) cpu prosessing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your platform is Linux/Unix, you can use [queues](http://php.net/manual/en/function.msg-send.php).

- request 1 start
- request 1 makes action
- request 1 sleeps and reading queue (sleep(1) and read queue)
- request 2 start
- request 2 makes action
- request 2 sending message to queue
- request 1 receives message from queue, wakes up and sends the new data
- request 1 sleeps again

Whith [semaphores](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sem-acquire.php) you can do this without `sleep()` even, but it will be more difficult to code.

Comment: thanks oz_ msg_receve blocks for me which is perfect for my goal

Comment: as it blocks, ill chack and report its cpu usge so far you are looking good

Comment: mmmm, sry for the late resonce but is there a way to distribute a message to be receved by any listener?

Comment: @borrel this message can be recieved by any listener.

Comment: im sorry with distribute i ment send a message to muliple listeners and let them all proccess it

Comment: to claify: now only one listener starts processing

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would have to use [pcntl_signal()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php), along with [pcntl_fork()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php). The server would have to support forking though.

As for the cpu processing load use [usleep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) in the loop so that the processor has time to be used by other processes.

Answer (score 0):

ideally, I would write this with the requests or "jobs" for the purposes of this being written to a database.

script 1 does something and writes a "job" to the DB
script 1 sleeps for an interval, then checkes to see if there is a returncode for that job in the DB, if so then
act
else sleep/repeat

script 2 checks for uncompleted jobs in the DB
if so then
act and write returncode
else sleep/repeat

Comment: i wanted to avoid the sleep;check;sleep prosegure,in signalling you would all a get_nextmesg() whisch sleeps until you receve a message in the que